# What use does an ORM have for database metadata?

Tags: database, orm, metadata

I was reading about ORMs and one of the descriptions I read said that the ORM interacts with database metadata.

Why is this important or relevant?

Metadata, as I understand, is just a way of describing what the database contains. So, for example, the database might have an internal table that lists what user tables have been created. Why would something like this be useful to an ORM?

Comment: This better not be a homework question!

Comment: If this is a homework question I want to know where mihai is going to school.  I was never introduced to these kind of concepts in school. :)

Comment: The accusation is beyond ridiculous.

Comment: @mihai: "beyond ridiculous" is pretty well meaningless.  Perhaps you have something more useful to contribute?

Comment: @S.Lott - I don't understand the accusation nor am I interested in defending myself against it. Close the question if you're offended by the suggestion that it might be homework. But I don't understand why this question is being singled out. I'm trying to understand a concept I'm not familiar with. That doesn't mean I'm a student. How many questions get asked here every day without the questioner being accused of doing homework? And given that, shouldn't the burden be on the accuser to clearly explain the rationale for the accusation? All I see is an assertion. I will not defend myself further

Comment: @mihai: Your interest in "defending" yourself isn't interesting.  Try not to be a jerk.  Stackoverflow is easy homework answers.  Some questions sound like homework.  Generally, well-written, thoughtful, open-ended questions sound like home.   Your question was exceptionally well-written, which makes it sound like homework.  You can respond with junk answers ("beyond ridiculous") or you can be a jerk.  However, your question was suspiciously good.

Comment: @mihai - If it makes you feel better my comment was defending you. :)

Comment: @mihai: I didn't get a reputation of 50K+ on the basis of a few good answers.  I read a **lot** of questions each day.  I'd like to actually **know** if this is homework with a simple "yes" or "no".  For example, there are a either four people asking bioinformatic homework questions or one person with four separate ID's.  I'd like to actually **know** the answer.

Comment: @S.Lott - Perhaps you have something more useful to contribute? I would suggest you spend more time answering questions and less time on police work.

Comment: +close: @mihai: I'm asking a simple question -- is this homework?  The level of evasion is shocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ORM uses the metadata to generate the code used to access the tables.  For example, if it's a date column then it generates the code to deal with that column as a date.

It will read foreign keys and primary keys to build relationships in the code as well as for generating the proper SQL syntax.

This is just a few of the ways it uses the metadata.

Comment: I see. So, as in your example of a date column, the ORM needs the metadata to determine exactly what 'type' of date column to translate the domain model to - e.g. DateTime, Date, Timestamp.

Comment: I just found this:
http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/08/build-your-own-data-access-layer-series/
It's from a contributer of NHibernate, who loves NHibernate but was in a situation where they had to for a client.  It has some good insight into a simple DAL that uses Metadata to do some of the "lifting" for you.

Answer (score 4):

What this means is that the ORM maps the schema, or structure, of the database to objects.  Typically, this means mapping tables to classes (User table to User class), fields to attributes (Age field to User.Age attribute), and each record then represents an instance of that object.

Comment: Right. So in the case of field-to-attribute, whether it's a VARCHAR or INTEGER will detmine what the type of the attribute will be when it translates it for the corresponding class instance.